# grid-template-columns not working in grids

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I just started learining css grids. I created a HTML file with seven divs. I am trying to convert width of each div to 50% using `grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr`, but this is not working. All divs just take the whole width of body.

I didn't understood why it behaves like that. Explain me why all the divs take whole space instead of taking only 50% of space.

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  border: 0.5px solid black;
  height: 100px;
}

#one{background-color:#9f9}
#two{background-color:#f99}
#three{background-color:#99f}
#four{background-color:#555}
#five{background-color:rgb(25, 233, 25)}
#six{background-color:rgb(255, 214, 153)}
#seven{background-color:rgb(255, 253, 153)}
```

```html
<div id=one></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
<div id="four"></div>
<div id="five"></div>
<div id="six"></div>
<div id="seven"></div>
```

Comment: the grid template should be defined on the grid element so the body

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `grid-template-columns` property applies to the grid container, so put it in the same declaration as `display: grid`.

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  border: 0.5px solid black;
  height: 100px;
}

#one{background-color:#9f9}
#two{background-color:#f99}
#three{background-color:#99f}
#four{background-color:#555}
#five{background-color:rgb(25, 233, 25)}
#six{background-color:rgb(255, 214, 153)}
#seven{background-color:rgb(255, 253, 153)}
```

```html
<div id=one></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
<div id="four"></div>
<div id="five"></div>
<div id="six"></div>
<div id="seven"></div>
```